# What is the runtime performance of Ethereum Libraries compared to Contracts?

Tags: solidity, gas, library, upgrading

I'm looking for the cheapest way (in terms of gas price) to design upgradeable contracts. I don't expect many upgrades.
Being inspired by [Writing upgradable contracts in Solidity](https://blog.colony.io/writing-upgradeable-contracts-in-solidity-6743f0eecc88), I'm investigating the use of [libraries](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#libraries) for logic implementation for a contract (so separating storage from the logic).
One obvious advantage is to only deploy once (or reuse already deployed) libraries and not contaminating the Blockchain with repetitive code.

**Are there any runtime penalties (performance) of using libraries rather then contract inheritance?**

The article mentioned above says:

> With libraries, there is a slight gas overhead on each call. However, it makes deploying a new contract much cheaper.

But it doesn't clarify what is the overhead.
**If the overhead still exists, are there any plans to eliminate it?**